# Android Vertical Text view - display character one below another as show below

Tags: android, textview, vertical-alignment

I want to display the text in vertical text view (i.e. characters should be placed one below another as below)
a
b
c
d

I wish to do this in a single text view.
We can turn the entire text by using android:toDegrees="-90" or "90" but i want to display as shown above which is not achieved with android:toDegress tag.

Appreciate your help!

**UPDATE**
I will get the String from another app through AIDL which is subjected to change as per the sender, in addition, he will send me a flag to display the text in a vertical or horizontal direction. Based on the flag I should display accordingly. I have no problem with a horizontal view as it is the default one but to display it in vertical(as shown above) I need help.

Comment: What do you mean by vertical? What is the separator? Space?

Comment: Vertical means the character should be shown one below another rather than adjacent. I was looking for an option in a TextView which will have an inbuilt option to change the given string 'abcd' into the way as shown in my question. I really didn't think of any separator to get this view but after seeing below two answers I feel that we can achieve this kind of display through the insertion of '\n' new line.

Comment: Yes, `TextView` does not support this by default

Comment: Fine then, Thanks @Bach Vu for your timely answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add line break to your string with either `\n` or `<br>`

With `\n`:

```
<string name="sample_string">a\nb\nc\nd</string>
textView.setText(R.string.sample_string)
```

With `<br>`:

```
<string name="sample_string"><![CDATA[a<br />b<br />c<br />d]]></string>
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(context.getString(R.string.sample_string))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helps me to display as I intended but I wish to know is there any inbuilt options with 'TextView' which can do this. My string is a dynamic one which I get from a different method so I need to modify the String to adapt your approach.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

If String is Dynamic then you can add `\n` after each character.

```
private String build(String str){
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(str.charAt(0));
        for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
                builder.append("\n"+str.charAt(i));
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
    return "";
}


 textView.setText(build("abcd"));
```

It will show vertically. This way text can go out of Bound so you should make `TextView` scrollable  in this case.